# is there a way to integrate data lookup and normalization routines into apache spark processing pipeline?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

As a service provider, we have multiple incident/ticketing systems, from which we are planning to steam data through Apache Spark. One of the challenges is, that each of these ticketing systems have adopted their own semantical meaning of things like "incident priority", and a few other.
This situation forces us to run these incident record through a lookup / normalization routines, which adjust the semantics back to a common meaning.
My question is: is it possible to introduce such lookup / normalization routine into the Spark stream processing pipeline?

Comment: This is rather vague description but if you think that Spark and Spark streaming are right tools for the job in general then lookups and cleaning routines shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The intent is to write a routine in PySpark, which processes every incoming streaming record, performs a lookup from a MongoDB (located on each processing node), modifies each record, and passes that record along for further consumption. Is this a plausible scenario?

Comment: @Eugene Sounds like an extremely common scenario for spark streaming.

Comment: @EugeneGoldberg, I would suggest that this "lookup" table that will help you to normalize semantics will be cached in spark as broadcast variable, if data is not too big. If data is big, might be that  you can implement 1 time extraction(for current processing cycle) and convert this data as native spark RDD(so you'll join your input stream with this RDD to do the normalization). From my experience any such lookup aside(to external service) will cost you in overall throughput(caching might help too). Anyway it's doable and will work.

Comment: @Igor Berman, In my case, we are talking less then 1000 lookup records, so the idea of broadcast variable should work fine. From time to time, some of the lookup values will change. Is there a way to "re-broadcast" such updates?

Comment: @EugeneGoldberg, depends. Are you going to use spark streaming or some kind of cron-scheduled batch jobs(say once per hour)? Second variant is simple to implement - just prepare broadcast on every startup. In first probably harder - not sure how to do it.

Comment: @IgorBerman, OK, I can see how this could work: Apache Kafka would front-end Spark, so, when Spark restarted after lookup value update, it could drain Kafka queue, and continue its processing.